# AmpScript vars not being set when comparing now() to string

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I have the following block of AmpScript at the top of an email in Marketing Cloud

```
%%[
var @now, @cdp, @bookingStart, @bookingEnd, @pickupStart, @pickupEnd

SET @now = now()

/* MAY17 */
IF (now() > "5/18/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "6/08/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "18/05/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "08/16/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "19/05/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "14/06/2017"

/* JUN17 */
ELSEIF (now() > "6/15/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "6/30/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "15/06/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "30/06/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "16/06/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "30/06/2017"
SET @now = "JUNE"

/* JUL17 */
ELSEIF (now() > "7/20/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "8/10/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "20/07/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "10/08/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "18/08/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "08/09/2017"

/* AUG17 */
ELSEIF (now() >= "8/17/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() <= "9/07/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "17/08/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "07/09/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "09/09/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "30/09/2017"

/* SEP17 */
ELSEIF (now() > "9/21/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "10/12/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "21/09/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "12/10/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "22/09/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "18/10/2017"

/* OCT17 */
ELSEIF (now() > "10/19/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "11/09/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "19/10/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "09/11/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "20/10/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "15/11/2017"

/* NOV17 */
ELSEIF (now() > "11/16/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "12/07/2017 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "16/11/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "07/12/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "17/11/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "14/12/2017"

/* DEC17 */
ELSEIF (now() > "12/21/2017 00:00 AM" AND now() < "1/11/2018 23:59 PM") THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "21/12/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "11/01/2018"
SET @pickupStart = "27/12/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "28/01/2018"
ENDIF
]%%
```

In the body of the email I am outputting all the variables in the IF block, but get an empty string back for each one.

```
... by %%=v(@bookingEnd)=%% using CDP %%=v(@cdp)=%%. ...
```

The output of `%%=v(@now)=%%` is

> 6/14/2017 7:48:08 AM

Note: Actual CDP codes have been replaced with "***" in the above code.

Comment: Does @bookingEnd output anything, or is it blank as well?

Comment: Hi @Gortonington sorry should have clarified that. Yes all variables in the IF block are blank.

Comment: Some of the dates aren't covered, for example in your first IF it goes from 5/18 to 6/08, but the next if statement only covers from 6/15 to 6/30.  Anything from 6/08 to 6/15 will get no info inserted as there is no ELSE condition. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Hi @Gortonington yeah... this is not on purpose! Just saw that myself and came back to update the question. Reason I'm not getting a variable back is because today's date is not covered in the IF statement... man, what an idiot! Feel free to add this as the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your dates are not covered inside your IF statement.

For example in your first IF statement it goes from 5/18 to 6/08, but the next IF statement only covers from 6/15 to 6/30. Anything from 6/08 to 6/15 will get no info inserted as there is no ELSE condition.

I would recommend either covering each date, or adding a 'catch all' ELSE statement to handle those that do not fit inside the specified dates.

Also, for brevity and efficiency's sake, I would change the way you are handling the date as a variable by using FORMATDATE().

See below as an example:

```
%%[
var @now, @cdp, @bookingStart, @bookingEnd, @pickupStart, @pickupEnd

SET @now = FORMATDATE(Now(), "YYYYMMDD")

/* MAY17 */
IF (@now > 20170518 AND @now < 20170608) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "18/05/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "08/16/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "19/05/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "14/06/2017"

/* JUN17 */
ELSEIF (@now > 20170615 AND @now < 20170630) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "15/06/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "30/06/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "16/06/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "30/06/2017"
SET @now = "JUNE"

/* JUL17 */
ELSEIF (@now > 20170720 AND @now < 20170810) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "20/07/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "10/08/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "18/08/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "08/09/2017"

/* AUG17 */
ELSEIF (@now >= 20170817 AND @now <= 20170907) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "17/08/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "07/09/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "09/09/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "30/09/2017"

/* SEP17 */
ELSEIF (@now > 20170921 AND @now < 20171012) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "21/09/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "12/10/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "22/09/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "18/10/2017"

/* OCT17 */
ELSEIF (@now > 20171019 AND @now < 20171109) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "19/10/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "09/11/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "20/10/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "15/11/2017"

/* NOV17 */
ELSEIF (@now > 20171116 AND @now < 20171207) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "16/11/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "07/12/2017"
SET @pickupStart = "17/11/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "14/12/2017"

/* DEC17 */
ELSEIF (@now > 20171221 AND @now < 20180111) THEN
SET @cdp = "***"
SET @bookingStart = "21/12/2017"
SET @bookingEnd = "11/01/2018"
SET @pickupStart = "27/12/2017"
SET @pickupEnd = "28/01/2018"

ELSE

 /* Your catch all info */

ENDIF
]%%
```